# Removing a Marionette EventAggregator: really necessary to prevent leaks?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, command, marionette, eventaggregator

I'm reading the `EventAggregator` doc in [Backbone.Wreqr](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr). It can be used like the following.

```
MyApp.vent.trigger("some:namespaced:event");

MyApp.vent.on("some:namespaced:event", function(){
  // ...
});
```

I cannot understand if, once set up an handler within a view, I need to remove it or Marionette will do it for me in `onClose` method or somewhere else? If I need to remove it, what is the best approach I can follow? Is it necessary just to `off` that event? Does the same apply for [`Commands`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.commands.md) using `removeHandler`?

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of your situation.
If you don't  want to listen some event, when module doesn't work, you can subscribe to module "stop" event and execute off for all necessary events.

```
module.on("stop", function(){
  App.vent.off(someMethods);
});
```

As usuall, view doesn't use global event aggregation.
But if you use, you shuold use

```
this.listenTo( App.vent, "someEvent", function(){...} )
```

and then Marionette remove this handler.